# Rcpp: "overloaded function with no contextual type information" for R::dbeta

Tags: c++, r, random, overloading, rcpp

I have C++ code with the Rcpp package included.

Within a function I have the following loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
   double yi = y[i], xi = X_chain[i];
        
   double numerator = R::dbeta( yi, alpha_par, beta, log=false );
   double denumerator = R::dbeta( xi, alpha_par, beta, log=false );
   double alpha = std::min(1.0,(numerator)/(denumerator));
   
   (...)

}
```

where alpha_par and beta are doubles and they are the parameters of the beta distribution.

For both lines where I use the function R::dbeta I get the error "overloaded function with no contextual type information". I am really confused since runif and rbinom at different points in the code are working completely fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I am reproducing the same issue as you have when just running `R::dbeta(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, log = false)` but I don't think you should name parameters in C++. E.g. simply doing `R::dbeta(0.5, 1.0, 1.0, false)` works for me.

Comment: Ditto, a very quick and very naive check as in `Rcpp::evalCpp("R::dbeta(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, false") ` resolves just fine (and gets the same answer as `dbeta(0,5, 0.5, 0.5)` in R).

Comment: Thank you. Yea, I am more used to R than C++, so this was not even thing I thought about. Taking out the "log=" part solved it for me. Thanks alot, it's working now for me, too.